# How to find the top k pairwise product of in an array of integers?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, sorting, arrays

**Input**: An array $a$ of integers $[a_{1}, \cdots, a_{n}]$, and a positive integer $k$.

**Output**: The the top-k products of pairs in $a$.

**Example**: $a = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1],k=3$ , output $(42,35,30)$, with corresponding pairs $(7,6),(7,5),(6,5)$.

A naive solution would can be done in $O(k^{2}\log{k} + n\log{n})$, which sort the array first and enumerate over the cartesian product of the first $k$ elements.

I can afford the cost of sorting the array but when $k$ is large, $k^{2}\log{k}$ is costly, is there any better solution?

Comment: This is a classical question which can be solved in $O(n\log n + k\log k)$. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000512/find-the-top-k-sums-of-two-sorted-arrays) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, but the the link is about top k sum, not top k product.

Comment: @Keith What is the difference?

Comment: It's basically the same problem. Assuming for simplicity that all elements are positive, you can convert product to sum by taking log (though in this particular case, you can just run the same algorithms).

Comment: If elements are allowed to be zero or negative, you need to work a bit harder, using the original algorithm as a black box. Details left to you.

Comment: @gnasher729, no difference, I got it

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, thanks very much, I have tried and it can be used without transforming to log, since the right and down direction is still monotonous, no matter sum or product. Thanks for suggestion.